# TypeError: Cannot read porperty 'setVoiceChannel' of undefined | Trying to move a user with discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am using the discord.js API and I am trying to move a certain user in a certain voicechannel, by using the [setVoiceChannel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=setVoiceChannel) methode.

```
client.on('message', message => {

    console.log(message.content);

    const member = message.guild.members.get('user id');

    if (message.content == 'example'){


       member.setVoiceChannel('channel id');

    }
```

I also am not quite sure how to define "member" to a certain user. I guess member gets returned by tfor example text message.
However the Error is the following:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'setVoiceChannel' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

When using the `get` Method on a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection) you need to actually provide the ID of the member, instead of literally writing `user id`.

Example:

```js
message.guild.members.get("214298654863917059"); //hard coding a string
message.guild.members.get(message.author.id); //using a variable
```

Additionally, the use of the get Method is unnessacery in this specific case, as you can already get the [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) object from your available [message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) object by reading `message.member`, making this a more ideal solution:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    console.log(message.content);

    const member = message.member;
    if (message.content == 'example'){
       member.setVoiceChannel('channel id'); //make sure to actually use a valid id here
}
```

Comment: I know the aspect with the user ID. I just wrote "user id" as an example since i didnt want to give this guys id away. however I figured it out. I just made a typo in the config file.
but thanks anyway